# ufunc 'boxcox1p' not supported for the input types. the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm having this code (for machine learning) below:

```
from scipy.special import boxcox1p
from scipy.special import boxcox
from scipy.special import inv_boxcox
df_trans=df1.apply(lambda x: boxcox1p(x,0.0))
```

With `df1` being a dataframe containing date and some other values

However, after running the above codes, I got this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [585], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 from scipy.special import boxcox
      3 from scipy.special import inv_boxcox
----> 4 df_trans=df1.apply(lambda x: boxcox1p(x,0.0))

TypeError: ufunc 'boxcox1p' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

How do I fix this?

Edited: This is part of the code sample:

```
    Quantity   Price        Difference  Money Received
0   55419      12.908304    8.518790    69665.133754
1   45179      28.492719    8.518790    125359.752289
2   11985      17.040535    18.776097   19888.813469
```

Comment: Please include a sample of your dataframe in text format. This way people will actually be able to use the data to try and reproduce your problem. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: oh okok, i added part of it

Comment: Running your code on this data sample does not produce an error.  You mentioned that you have a date column too? If a date column is added (being of `datetime` type) to your sample, this exact error comes up. You probably don't intend to perform a transformation on date values, so exclude that column.

Comment: OHH it works now, TYSM Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this is to exclude date column. Special thanks to @AlexK for helping!